# How do I edit the code that calculates the value for the four weeks of the month for all months with pl/sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I divided the month into four weeks and printed the amount for each week. How do I set this up with a loop for 12 months?

```
declare 
    cursor c is 
    select varis_tar, tutar 
  from muhasebe.doviz_takip
  where trunc(varis_tar) BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/10/2021', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND
  TO_DATE('31/10/2021', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
  group by varis_tar,tutar;
  tutar1 number(13,2):=0; 
  tutar2 number(13,2):=0; 
  tutar3 number(13,2):=0;
  tutar4 number(13,2):=0; 

begin  
    
 for r in c loop

    if r.varis_tar between   TO_DATE('01/10/2021', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND
  TO_DATE('07/10/2021', 'DD/MM/YYYY') then  
    tutar1:=(r.tutar)+tutar1;
    --message(r.tutar);
    
    elsif r.varis_tar between   TO_DATE('07/10/2021', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND
  TO_DATE('14/10/2021', 'DD/MM/YYYY') then 
    tutar2:=(r.tutar)+tutar2;
  --message(r.tutar);
    
    elsif r.varis_tar between   TO_DATE('14/10/2021', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND
  TO_DATE('21/10/2021', 'DD/MM/YYYY') then 
    tutar3:=(r.tutar)+tutar3;
  --message(r.tutar);
    
    elsif r.varis_tar between   TO_DATE('21/10/2021', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND
  TO_DATE('31/10/2021', 'DD/MM/YYYY') then 
    tutar4:=(r.tutar)+tutar4;
    --message(r.tutar);

    end if;
 end loop;
```

I tried to get the dates the same way for all the months. I tried that, but it worked wrong.

```
  where trunc(varis_tar) BETWEEN TO_DATE('1', 'DD') AND
  TO_DATE('31', 'DD')

    if r.varis_tar between   TO_DATE('1', 'DD') AND
  TO_DATE('07', 'DD') then  
    
    elsif r.varis_tar between   TO_DATE('7', 'DD') AND
  TO_DATE('14', 'DD') then 
    
    elsif r.varis_tar between   TO_DATE('14', 'DD') AND
  TO_DATE('21', 'DD') then 
    
    elsif r.varis_tar between   TO_DATE('21', 'DD') AND
  TO_DATE('31', 'DD') then
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'am understanding it correctly but:

try `if extract(day from varis_tar) between 1 and 7`

or more complex

```
l_week := to_char(varis_tar,'W'); --week number
if l_week = 1 then --first week
elsif l_week = 2 etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several issues:

- `date` in Oracle is actually a datetime, so `between` will not count any time after the midnight of the upper boundary.
- you count the midnight of the week's end twice: in current week and in the next week (`between` includes both boundaries).
- you do not need any PL/SQL and especially a cursor loop, because it occupy resources during calculation outside of SQL context.

Use datetime format to calculate weeks, because it is easy to read and understand. Then group by corresponding components.

> ```
> with a as (
>   select
>     date '2021-01-01' - 1 + level as dt
>     , level as val
>   from dual
>   connect by level < 400
> )
> , b as (
> select
>   dt
>   , val
>   /*Map 29, 30 and 31 to 28*/
>   , to_char(
>       least(dt, trunc(dt, 'mm') + 27)
>       , 'yyyymmw'
>   ) as w
> from a
> )
> select
>   substr(w, 1, 4) as y
>   , substr(w, 5, 2) as m
>   , substr(w, -1) as w
>   , sum(val) as val
>   , min(dt) as dt_from
>   , max(dt) as dt_to
> from b
> group by
>   w
> ```
>
> ```
> Y    | M  | W  |  VAL | DT_FROM    | DT_TO     
> :--- | :- | :- | ---: | :--------- | :---------
> 2021 | 01 | 1  |   28 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-07
> 2021 | 01 | 2  |   77 | 2021-01-08 | 2021-01-14
> 2021 | 01 | 3  |  126 | 2021-01-15 | 2021-01-21
> 2021 | 01 | 4  |  265 | 2021-01-22 | 2021-01-31
> 2021 | 02 | 1  |  245 | 2021-02-01 | 2021-02-07
> 2021 | 02 | 2  |  294 | 2021-02-08 | 2021-02-14
> 2021 | 02 | 3  |  343 | 2021-02-15 | 2021-02-21
> 2021 | 02 | 4  |  392 | 2021-02-22 | 2021-02-28
> 2021 | 03 | 1  |  441 | 2021-03-01 | 2021-03-07
> 2021 | 03 | 2  |  490 | 2021-03-08 | 2021-03-14
> 2021 | 03 | 3  |  539 | 2021-03-15 | 2021-03-21
> 2021 | 03 | 4  |  855 | 2021-03-22 | 2021-03-31
> 2021 | 04 | 1  |  658 | 2021-04-01 | 2021-04-07
> 2021 | 04 | 2  |  707 | 2021-04-08 | 2021-04-14
> 2021 | 04 | 3  |  756 | 2021-04-15 | 2021-04-21
> 2021 | 04 | 4  | 1044 | 2021-04-22 | 2021-04-30
> 2021 | 05 | 1  |  868 | 2021-05-01 | 2021-05-07
> 2021 | 05 | 2  |  917 | 2021-05-08 | 2021-05-14
> 2021 | 05 | 3  |  966 | 2021-05-15 | 2021-05-21
> 2021 | 05 | 4  | 1465 | 2021-05-22 | 2021-05-31
> 2021 | 06 | 1  | 1085 | 2021-06-01 | 2021-06-07
> 2021 | 06 | 2  | 1134 | 2021-06-08 | 2021-06-14
> 2021 | 06 | 3  | 1183 | 2021-06-15 | 2021-06-21
> 2021 | 06 | 4  | 1593 | 2021-06-22 | 2021-06-30
> 2021 | 07 | 1  | 1295 | 2021-07-01 | 2021-07-07
> 2021 | 07 | 2  | 1344 | 2021-07-08 | 2021-07-14
> 2021 | 07 | 3  | 1393 | 2021-07-15 | 2021-07-21
> 2021 | 07 | 4  | 2075 | 2021-07-22 | 2021-07-31
> 2021 | 08 | 1  | 1512 | 2021-08-01 | 2021-08-07
> 2021 | 08 | 2  | 1561 | 2021-08-08 | 2021-08-14
> 2021 | 08 | 3  | 1610 | 2021-08-15 | 2021-08-21
> 2021 | 08 | 4  | 2385 | 2021-08-22 | 2021-08-31
> 2021 | 09 | 1  | 1729 | 2021-09-01 | 2021-09-07
> 2021 | 09 | 2  | 1778 | 2021-09-08 | 2021-09-14
> 2021 | 09 | 3  | 1827 | 2021-09-15 | 2021-09-21
> 2021 | 09 | 4  | 2421 | 2021-09-22 | 2021-09-30
> 2021 | 10 | 1  | 1939 | 2021-10-01 | 2021-10-07
> 2021 | 10 | 2  | 1988 | 2021-10-08 | 2021-10-14
> 2021 | 10 | 3  | 2037 | 2021-10-15 | 2021-10-21
> 2021 | 10 | 4  | 2995 | 2021-10-22 | 2021-10-31
> 2021 | 11 | 1  | 2156 | 2021-11-01 | 2021-11-07
> 2021 | 11 | 2  | 2205 | 2021-11-08 | 2021-11-14
> 2021 | 11 | 3  | 2254 | 2021-11-15 | 2021-11-21
> 2021 | 11 | 4  | 2970 | 2021-11-22 | 2021-11-30
> 2021 | 12 | 1  | 2366 | 2021-12-01 | 2021-12-07
> 2021 | 12 | 2  | 2415 | 2021-12-08 | 2021-12-14
> 2021 | 12 | 3  | 2464 | 2021-12-15 | 2021-12-21
> 2021 | 12 | 4  | 3605 | 2021-12-22 | 2021-12-31
> 2022 | 01 | 1  | 2583 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-07
> 2022 | 01 | 2  | 2632 | 2022-01-08 | 2022-01-14
> 2022 | 01 | 3  | 2681 | 2022-01-15 | 2022-01-21
> 2022 | 01 | 4  | 3915 | 2022-01-22 | 2022-01-31
> 2022 | 02 | 1  | 1194 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-02-03
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=59d1551a08b87f0a7a96903cda201fda)*

Or the same in columns:

> ```
> with a as (
>   select
>     date '2021-01-01' - 1 + level as dt
>     , level as val
>   from dual
>   connect by level < 400
> )
> , b as (
> select
>   val
>   /*Map 29, 30 and 31 to 28*/
>   , to_char(dt, 'yyyymm') as m
>   , to_char(
>       least(dt, trunc(dt, 'mm') + 27)
>       , 'w'
>   ) as w
> from a
> )
> select
>   substr(m, 1, 4) as y
>   , substr(m, 5, 2) as m
>   , tutar1
>   , tutar2
>   , tutar3
>   , tutar4
> from b
> pivot(
>   sum(val)
>   for w in (
>     1 as tutar1, 2 as tutar2
>     , 3 as tutar3, 4 as tutar4
>   )
> )
> ```
>
> ```
> Y    | M  | TUTAR1 | TUTAR2 | TUTAR3 | TUTAR4
> :--- | :- | -----: | -----: | -----: | -----:
> 2021 | 01 |     28 |     77 |    126 |    265
> 2021 | 02 |    245 |    294 |    343 |    392
> 2021 | 03 |    441 |    490 |    539 |    855
> 2021 | 04 |    658 |    707 |    756 |   1044
> 2021 | 05 |    868 |    917 |    966 |   1465
> 2021 | 06 |   1085 |   1134 |   1183 |   1593
> 2021 | 07 |   1295 |   1344 |   1393 |   2075
> 2021 | 08 |   1512 |   1561 |   1610 |   2385
> 2021 | 09 |   1729 |   1778 |   1827 |   2421
> 2021 | 10 |   1939 |   1988 |   2037 |   2995
> 2021 | 11 |   2156 |   2205 |   2254 |   2970
> 2021 | 12 |   2366 |   2415 |   2464 |   3605
> 2022 | 01 |   2583 |   2632 |   2681 |   3915
> 2022 | 02 |   1194 |   null |   null |   null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=19353dc6e915f03f3dbab622fcd2986f)*